# About Quick Start of Deep Learning(Knet.jl) by Julia language

Tags: deep-learning, julia, conv-neural-network

julia language deep learning framework,
This is a quick start for Knet.jl,
https://denizyuret.github.io/Knet.jl/latest/tutorial/#Tutorial

```
ENV ["COLUMNS"] = 72
using Knet, MLDatasets, IterTools
struct Conv; w; b; f; end
(c :: Conv) (x) = c.f. (pool (conv4 (c.w, x). + C.b))
Conv (w1, w2, cx, cy, f = relu) = Conv (param (w1, w2, cx, cy), param0 (1,1, cy, 1), f);
```

The complex type Conv has three fields, w, b, and f.

The Conv type c (x) function broadcasts the next function with the f function.

The inner product of the w matrix and the x matrix is ​​calculated with conv4 (c.w, x), and the addition with c.b is performed with. +.

I don't know what the pool is looking for in that matrix.

This (pool (conv4 ...)) is passed through the relu activation function.

At the last Conv (w1, w2, cx, cy, f = relu) = Conv (param (w1, w2, cx, cy), param0 (1,1, cy, 1), f);
I don't know what I'm trying to do.

This is the situation of understanding.
What are you trying to do, especially in the pool?
Why are there two params on the 5th line?
I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the layer does a convolution followed by max pooling:

> Pooling layers reduce the dimensions of the data by combining the outputs of neuron clusters at one layer into a single neuron in the next layer. Local pooling combines small clusters, typically 2 x 2. Global pooling acts on all the neurons of the convolutional layer. There are two common types of pooling: max and average. Max pooling uses the maximum value of each cluster of neurons at the prior layer, while average pooling instead uses the average value. (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Pooling_layers)

There are two `params` on the 5th line, because a convolutional layers has two trainable parameters: the kernel weights `w` and the bias `b`. The function `param` (and `param0`) initialize them with the correct size and mark them as trainable parameters that will be updated during the optimization.

To learn neural networks, I found these examples: [linear regression](https://github.com/denizyuret/Knet.jl/blob/master/examples/housing-linreg/housing.jl) and a simple [feed-forward network (multilayer perceptron)](https://github.com/denizyuret/Knet.jl/blob/master/examples/mnist-mlp/mlp.jl) quite useful.